# Cannot resolve symbol 'ImmutableList' in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I try to implement Google Play Pay but don`t know how solve this problem：Type of **ImmutableList** cannot be resoclved.
Should I import some package?

I have search with Google and no any question like this(Android studio)

```
ImmutableList.of(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                            .setProductId("product_id_example")
                                            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                            .build())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run into the same problem. By hovering with the pointer over 'ImmutableList' I selected the entry `Add dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlitics-builtools and import...`

This action created the following line in the import section of my activity file

> import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.reloc.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

and the following line in the build.gradle file:

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.7.1'
> ```

However, the word `reloc` in the import line initially appeared in red color with the hint *Cannot resolve symbol 'reloc'*. Then I noticed that in the build.gradle file, android studio was offering to change the version of the crashlytics-buildtools from 2.7.1 to 2.9.1. After doing so and syncing gradle, the word `reloc` was no longer red and `ImmutableList` was recognized correctly.

I wonder whether it is really necessary to import the firebase crashlytics-buildtools for the integration of the Google Billing Library (I use it for an app with in-app purchases) or if there is a more simple way to do this.

Comment: Although I got to bypass the problem, thanks for your help and I can successfully build it according to your instructions

Comment: Please note that using implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.7.1' adding extra 10 megabytes to relese APK/AAB file in folded /base/root/dump_syms.  Using implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android") reduce my APK from 20 to 10 megabytes.

Answer (score 10):

Android Studio suggests the firebase-crashlytics-buildtools dependency to import the ImmutableList class. Doing so resulted in a big increase of the file (bundle) size.

Try instead including guava as a dependency, if you are not using crashlythics in your app:

// graddle

implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android'

// java class/code

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

This has a much smaller impact on the file size. In my case, the bundle was 2MB compared to 10 MB if using crashlythics-buildtools.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I had been searched to reduce the apk size due to firebase-crashlytics-buildtools. At last I found your solution helpful a lot to reduce apk size about 8MB. Many thanks..